# Is there a Matlab function for calculating std of a binomial distribution?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a binary vector V, in which each entry describes success (1) or failure (0) in the relevant trial out of a whole session.
(the length of the vector denotes the number of trials in the session).
I can easily calculate the success rate of the session (by taking the mean of the vector i.e. (sum(V)/length(V))).

However I also need to know the variance or std of each session.

In order to calculate that, is it OK to use the Matlab std function (i.e. to take std(V)/length(V))?
Or, should I use something which is specifically suited for the binomial distribution?
Is there a Matlab std (or variance) function which is specific for a "success/failure" distribution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you satisfy the assumptions of the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution),

- a fixed number of *n* independent [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) trials,
- each with constant success probability *p*,

then I'm not sure that is necessary, since the parameters `n` and `p` are available from your data.

Note that we model **number of successes** (in *n* trials) as a random variable distributed with the Binomial(*n*,*p*) distribution.

```
n = length(V);
p = mean(V);     % equivalently, sum(V)/length(V)   
                 % the mean is the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for p
                 % note: need large n or replication to get true p
```

Then the **standard deviation of the number of successes** in `n` independent [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) trials with constant success probability `p` is just `sqrt(n*p*(1-p))`.

Of course you can assess this from your data if you have multiple samples.  Note this is different from `std(V)`.  In your data formatting, it would require having multiple vectors, `V1`, `V2`, `V2`, etc. (replication), then the sample **standard deviation of the number of successes** would obtained from the following.

```
% Given V1, V2, V3 sets of Bernoulli trials
std([sum(V1) sum(V2) sum(V3)])
```

---

**If you already know your parameters:** *n*, *p*

You can obtain it easily enough.

```
n = 10;
p = 0.65;
pd = makedist('Binomial',n, p)
std(pd)                                % 1.5083
```

or

```
sqrt(n*p*(1-p))                        % 1.5083
```

as discussed earlier.

---

**Does the standard deviation increase with** ***n*** **?**
The OP has [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755141/is-there-a-matlab-function-for-calculating-std-of-a-binomial-distribution/58755301#comment103880581_58755301):

> Something is bothering me.. if std = `sqrt(n*p*(1-p))`, then it increases with `n`. Shoudn't the std decrease when `n` increases?

**Confirmation & Derivation:**

Definitions:

[image: Definitions]

Then we know that
[image: Distribution]

Then just from definitions of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) we can show the variance (similarly for standard deviation if you add the square root) increases with `n`.

[image: Variance derivation]

Since the square root is a non-decreasing function, we know the same relationship holds for the standard deviation.

Comment: Something is bothering me.. if std = sqrt(n*p*(1-p)), then it increases with n. Shoudn't the std decreas when n increases? Thanks

Comment: @user135172 I've edited the answer to explain why this occurs.  Does this help?